# Meteor Insert invisibly and silently hanging

Tags: meteor

The following code does not update the database everytime a tweet is found - it silently hangs, adding no tweets to the database.

If a tweet is manually added to the DB from the JS console in the browser, it shows up just fine, but no tweets are being added to the DB automatically.

```
Tweets = new Meteor.Collection("tweets");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.kildeer.tweets = function () {
        return Tweets.find({});
    };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require,
        Twit = require('twit')
      , T = new Twit({
            consumer_key: 'blahblah',
            consumer_secret: 'blahblah',
            access_token: 'blahblah',
            access_token_secret: 'blahblah'
        });

      var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['bing', 'google', 'microsoft'] })

      stream.on('tweet', function (tweerp) {
            var id;
            console.log(tweerp.text);
            id = Tweets.insert({text: tweerp.text, screen_name: tweerp.user.screen_name, profile_image: tweerp.user.profile_image_url});
            console.log(id);
      });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Meteor, `Collection.insert` must always be called inside of a `Fiber()` closure.

```
Fiber(function() {
    Tweets.insert({text: tweerp.text, screen_name: tweerp.user.screen_name, profile_image: tweerp.user.profile_image_url});
}).run();
```